# Git commit message automatically add quote

Tags: git, github

Is it possible (or is it a bad idea) to set up automatically adding quote to git commit message? For example

```
$ git commit -m 'my commit message'
```

becomes

```
$ git commit -m my commit message
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use quotes, as your terminal expects. This is nothing particularly related to git. It 'can' be done using a alias-function or executable override. A good idea? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through Git itself, I would say that it would not be possible. This is because the -m flag expects one argument to be after it which is the message wrapped in quotes. If it is not wrapped in quotes, "my commit message" (one arg) would go to my commit message (three args).

However, everything is possible. You could write a bash script or something of the sort that could be aliased to "commit" that would iterate through all the words found after it and then wrap them in quotes and perform the necessary git commit command.

But this leads to your question, "is it a bad idea?". I don't think it is necessarily a bad idea, though I don't think it is a worthwhile venture and I personally wouldn't do it due to potential errors. By wrapping in quotes, you have a fail-safe that you typed your entire message and didn't accidentally hit enter or something before you were done.

So, I would suggest not doing it, but if you find it worth it, hopefully my suggestions would help.

EDIT:

I got curious and wanted to do it. This should provide the start if you choose to do it.

```
msg="git commit -m \""
for var in "$@"
do
    msg=$msg" "$var
done
msg=$msg\"
echo $msg
```

It's a simple bash script but it will take "./filename this is a message" and print "git commit -m "this is a message"". All you would have to do is actually perform the action instead of print it.

Word of warning though. All of those arguments will be executed. For example, if you include a wildcard like *.png, you will need to wrap that in quotes or else you will get all the files ending in png. And that would ultimately make this whole process useless to begin with.

Comment: You could also wrap this script in a git alias to perform a commit-like command and use it. Maybe `git cmt`?

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned to potentially alias it to "commit" but I think git cmt would make more sense. Still has some problems to it... but would generally work.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that the first time through. Yeah, I'm not sure that I'd remap commit. Never know when you might realize that this no-quoting stuff is kind of a bad idea. =)

Comment: I'd pray that he will never do  `git commit -m My commit message --someOtherOptions`

Comment: I he wants that, he will have to edit the script. I feel he just wants this option for a quick commit message and not for the advanced portions of Git